# how to find keystore file where is my sha1 key is saved

Tags: android, key, apk, sha1

I have changed my sha1 key but google will now allow me to upload apk with the new sha1 key so I have a backup where is my old sha1 key so If i get the extension i can replace my sha1 key to old one ...

how to know in  which extension sha1 key is stored  ?

Comment: Please help me  I'm in bigger trouble :(

Comment: C:\Users\The beast\AndroidStudioProjects\signedapk.jks   ? is here is my sha1 key is stored ??

Comment: Your keystore file is going to be where ever you stored it when you created it. It's good practice to make several backups of this file because if you lose it you won't be able to upload new APKs to the playstore.

Comment: @HuskyHuskie sir is there any way to store my old sha1 key to new jks file ? like i have old apk in which sha1 old is using so by that i can store it to new jks ?

Comment: As far as I know you would need to sign the app with the original keystore, if you were able to extract the keystore from the old APK that'd be a major security problem for every app on Android. The most common solution once you've lost the old keystore is to do a new release of the app under a new listing in the PlayStore.